# Old Russian Physics Papers?

Tags: resource-recommendations

Where can one find old Russian scientific papers in physics, say, in the Proceedings of the Russian Academy of Sciences or Zhurnal Eksperimentalnoy i Teoreticheskoy Fiziki? Can they be found online somewhere?

Comment: One of these decades the old JETP archive is gonna get DOIs and everything.

Answer (score 12):

JETP english archive (73-96), may be found here http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/e/index . Russian archive also starts at 73, so I think earlier versions may be found in libraries only.

I found some issues of Proceedings of the RAS here: http://elibrary.ru/issues.asp?id=7781 in Russian only. It seems that they are not translated at all. And normal electronic version does not exists even for Russian.

Comment: Thanks, Misha, I'm finding similar links but I need older than that. For instance, Басов и Прохоров ЖЭТФ, 27, 431 (1954) и Басов и Прохоров, Изв.АНСССР, 101, 47 (1945). It would be very nice if someone has them and can send them to my e-mail.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't solve the problem because recently the libraries are displacing these journals to remote locations and it's very hard to get them. I'm talking about the MIT, Harvard libraries or the libraries in NYC, Bobst Library or NY Public Library. I think the situation at Columbia U. is similar. Don't know what to do. Maybe one solution is to ask colleagues from Russia to kindly send copies over the net but I can't even find Russian chats that I could address this question.

Answer (score 10):

[Успехи физических наук](http://ufn.ru/ru/articles/)
1918-2011 years

For example - А.М. Прохоров, Н.Г. Басов [Молекулярный генератор и усилитель](http://ufn.ru/ru/articles/1955/11/d/) УФН 57 (11) (1955)

English version - [Physics-Uspekhi](http://ufn.ru/en/articles/) 1958-2011 years

Comment: @ganzewoort, It may be useful for you - [Collected papers](http://www.lebedev.ru/data/50laser/Beginning_of_the_Laser_Era_in_the_USSR.pdf) in russian and english.

Comment: again, thanks a bunch. This is of real help. Makes me woder, though, why isn't Basov and Prokhorov's 1945 paper included? Wou

Comment: Would you be able to find it for me? I'd appreciate it greatly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the collection of papers you gave a link to reveals more than I ever expectd, so I will be opening a special new question. Again, thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: @ganzewoort, reference "Басов и Прохоров, Изв.АНСССР, 101, 47 (1945)" is wrong, right is "Басов Н Г, Прохоров А М ДАН СССР 101 47 (1955)"